# Unbind bundle menu action command in Textmate2

Tags: key, unbind, textmatebundles, textmate2

I have fiddled around a bit with the bundle editor. For a bundle menu action I set the *Key equivalent* just to try it out, it worked great.

Now I'm trying to figure how to unbind/clear this specific bundle menu action. As of what I can see it's not possible through the bundle editor.

I've tried to remove both `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Cache` and `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Cache` but this won't do it.

Any ideas at all?

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it by upgrading TextMate2 to version **9113**. This version introduce a feature to clear key equivalents. See:

> Add clear button to key equivalent recorder.